# Link to a page and trigger toggle content on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

Good morning,

Since last week I am struggling with what looks like a common issue (considering the number of topic I have read about this matter): how to link a toggled content from another page.

I have been able to progress into this topic.
I am still facing a problem though (as usual, a solution or an answer leads to another issue!):

The link from another page to the toggled content works BUT it opens all the div of the page.
The question is straight forward though: How can I toggle the content of a single div?

My code is as follow (it is an extract of the content of the page - I have more than 2 div with toggled content). And yes, I know it is pretty ugly, but I am trying to make my way in the HTML/CSS and whatever without much help.

Many thanks!

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #ToggleTarget {
 display: none;
 }
</style>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
function Toggle() {
 var el = document.getElementById("ToggleTarget");
 if (el.style.display == "block") {
  el.style.display = "none";
 }
 else {
  el.style.display = "block";
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
<style type="text/css">
    #ToggleTarget2 {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
function Toggle2() {
 var el = document.getElementById("ToggleTarget2");
 if (el.style.display == "block") {
  el.style.display = "none";
 }
 else {
  el.style.display = "block";
 }
}
</SCRIPT>



<body>
<p><a href="javascript:Toggle();" name="link1"><span><strong>TITLE1</strong></span></a></p>
                                    <div class="ToggleTarget" id="ToggleTarget">
                                    <p align="justify">CONTENT1</div>
<p><a href="javascript:Toggle2();" name="link2"><span><strong>TITLE2</strong></span></a></p>
                                    <div class="ToggleTarget2" id="ToggleTarget2">
                                    <p align="justify">CONTENT2</div>
</body>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
if ( location.hash.length > 1 )
{
    Toggle( location.hash.substring(1) );
    Toggle2( location.hash.substring(1) );

}
</SCRIPT>
```

EDIT:
I guess the issue comes from:

```
if ( location.hash.length > 1 )
{
    Toggle( location.hash.substring(1) );
    Toggle2( location.hash.substring(1) );

}
```

If ( location.hash.length > 1 ), it opens both toggled content from the functions "Toggle" and "Toggle2". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by *"how to link a toggled content from another page"*?
Given your code, it seems you want an external link to lead to your page and toggle a div, right?

If that's the case, then there are a few things to change. First of all, this...

```
Toggle( location.hash.substring(1) );
```

...will not work as you want it to work. Indeed, your function `Toggle()` **takes no argument.**

However, you could make a more "generalized" version of your function, which would take as an argument the ID of the `div` to toggle:

```
function Toggle(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el.style.display == "block") {
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

And at the end of the page...

```
if (location.hash.length > 1) {
    Toggle(location.hash.substring(1));
}
```

If your page is named, for instance, `mypage.html`, then a link to `mypage.html#example-id` would load your page **and toggle the element of ID `example-id`.**

One last thing; instead of applying `display: none` to every togglable div, create a class `ToggleTarget` and give it `display: none`. Then, give this class to every togglable element you have, while giving them a unique ID.

### Working version

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ToggleTarget {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle(id) {
                var el = document.getElementById(id);
                if (el.style.display == "block") {
                    el.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    el.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="javascript:toggle('1');"><strong>TITLE1</strong></a></p>
        <div class="ToggleTarget" id="1">
            <p align="justify">CONTENT1</p>
        </div>
        <p><a href="javascript:toggle('2');"><strong>TITLE2</strong></a></p>
        <div class="ToggleTarget" id="2">
            <p align="justify">CONTENT2</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (location.hash.length > 1) {
                toggle(location.hash.substring(1));
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear yes, it is exactly what you said: an external link that lead to the page and toggle a - unique - div.

Right now, the code that I have linked works well but an external link open all the toggled div of the page.

I will give a try to the code you wrote above and come back to you.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: I have amended the code following your comment but all the toggled div are still getting opened - all of them - for any external link pointing to a specific div.

Comment: I have edited the part that seems dodgy to me. Please could you check back the edit above?
Many thanks!

Comment: Please read what I said in my post... 

**If that's the case, then there are a few things to change. First of all, Toggle( location.hash.substring(1) ); will not work. Indeed, your function Toggle() takes no argument.**

Comment: I've also edited my post with a working version based on what I said.

Comment: Let's say that I give the argument "development" to the the function Toggle. So it becomes Toggle(development). Alright. But then, how can I apply it to Toggle(location.hash.substring(1))? I switch "location" by "development"? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: (using my version of `toggle()`) `toggle("development");` (do not forget quotes) will togle the element of ID "development", while `toggle(location.hash.substring(1));` with the URL (for instance) page.html#foo will toggle the element of ID "foo". Indeed `location.hash.substring(1)` is replaced by whatever is after the #.

Comment: Awesome!! It works perfectly!
I have struggled for the past 30 minutes to understand why I had not the same result as yours and figured out that a damn "Toggle" instead of "toggle" was messing up everything.
Thanks so much! I'd like to vote for your answer but unfortunately I have not the required 15 of reputation to do so :(